# How to give nice look and feel other than nimbus on a java swing application

Tags: java, swing, themes

Looking for themes other than the default themes available like nimbus for my java swing application. As a beginner , i couldnt find anything , can anyone help me. Heard of JavaFX, but dont know how to use it.

Comment: As a user, I can tell you I personally prefer the system look and feel, it's comfortable and understand, just saying

Comment: do you know about javaFX and its application on a swing

Comment: JavaFx, was when it was announced, touted as a Flash competitor, until JavaFx2, it did not have a table or tree component, which, IMHO, are critical UI components for applications. There is now, also a move to introduce 3D into the core, so, as far as I can tell, JavaFX has no idea what it wants to be. Swing is old, and could use a over haul at the core, but it has a large community of very experienced developers behind it, which makes finding help much easier

Comment: The other "let down" of JavaFX, for is, the lack of support for system look and feels.  One of the greatest challenges of developing an application is use acceptance, sure, you're app might look "cool", but if all the users won't use it, what's it worth?  Presenting something to use the looks familiar and functions like other applications they are use to using immediately puts you over this hump.  I did this to the application I'm working (switch from metal to windows) and saw an increase of 75% of existing users and an immediate increase sales for sales (not a lot, but it was noticed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are asking is how to give your own custom look and feel Here is the code for you

```
class MyTheme extends DefaultMetalTheme {

   public String getName() { return "MyTheme"; }

    private final ColorUIResource primary1 = new ColorUIResource(255, 255, 0);
    private final ColorUIResource primary2 = new ColorUIResource(0, 255, 255);
    private final ColorUIResource primary3 = new ColorUIResource(255, 0, 255);

    protected ColorUIResource getPrimary1() { return primary1; }
    protected ColorUIResource getPrimary2() { return primary2; }
    protected ColorUIResource getPrimary3() { return primary3; }
}
```

And now in order to use this theme just use the following code

```
String lookAndFeel = UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName();
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lookAndFeel);
MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new MyTheme());
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
```

**UPDATE**
Screenshot added
[image]

The first one is default MetalLookAndFeel while the second one is MetalLookAndFeel with MyTheme added

Comment: Thanks... but like Metal theme, Nimbus theme, is there any other themes, or can we make use of some libraries.

Comment: @user3884321 If you take a look at [Modifying the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html), there is a section on Synthetic (Sync) which is a skinning look and feel, on which Nimbus is based, which might provide more information